# "Sideloaded" iOS app unavailable after sideloading to another device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I sideloaded my app (not open source) to an iPad Air, using Xcode and gave that iPad Air to my friend to test. All worked fine for him.

A couple of days later I made some changes and published my app to another iPad Air, using Xcode and now my friend's iPad says, "[AppName] is Unavailable".

I do not think that my friend even connected the iPad I gave him to the Internet.

I have not joined or paid the dues of the Apple Developer program.

Can you only sideload unpublished closed source apps to one device at a time?

What about if there is no Internet connection, aka the iPad is in Airplane mode?

If I remove the sideloaded app from the other iPad Air might it make the app on my friend's iPad work again?

Comment: apps will stop working after 2 days and need to be re-installed using Xcode if you have a free program membership

Comment: @Paulw11 I have the free membership, thanks for the info!

Comment: @Paulw11 go ahead and provide your answer and I will mark correct, I mention I have a free account in my question so it will make sense of other SO users